# External Hard disk not reachable after windows scan and fix error

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I used External hard disk in different PCs perfectly. every time I changed it to new PC it ask scanning for errors, the last use I scan the HD and then it hang and can't be accessible. I tried to show properties and to Enter it from CMD without any benefit. it hangs and I can't use it any more.

**please how to solve this problem?**

I used the program Partition Find and Mount without any useful result.

Comment: If it has been asking for error correction it's probably defective now, that being a symptom and a warning (like backup NOW, I'm about to die) . But another possible situation is incorrect usage, disconnecting while writing to it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia how to solve this problem?

Comment: Replace the drive if you can't even finish an error correction.